# Throw exception gives same message all the time

Tags: c#

I have a try and catch in my Main.cs

```
 try
 {
 }
  catch(exception e)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
 }
```

In a other class i have:

```
        if (....)            
        {
           //input
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Custom Error Message1"}
        }
```

In a other class i have a similar situation, but insteed the message is different here.
When a error occurs in the 2nd class the same message from the one above displays, what exactly is the cause of this and what could prove to be a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but don't think anyone can tell you what your problem is from the code snippets you provided :/

Comment: How do you know that the error occurs in the second class? Can you provide a full code sample?

Answer (score 1):

Have you examined the stack trace? That might tell you something, n'est-ce-pas?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, go to Debug-Exceptions and set Common Language Runtime exceptions to break when THROWN.  Now run your program in debug and you'll see which exception is actually being thrown and can examine the call stack.